# Installing GDAL on Ubuntu

Tags: python, gdal

I am not able to install gdal on Ubuntu using latest anaconda for python 3.6 How do I fix it? I get foll. error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - gdal -> numpy 1.8* -> python 2.6* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you try to install gdal with python 2.6 while your anaconda is python 3.6.

To install gdal (or any package) with a specific python version, create a conda environment:

```
$ conda create -n <myenvname> python=<version>
```

then activate the environment:

```
$ source activate <myenvname>
```

and then, install gdal:

```
$ conda install gdal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use conda, this install worked for me for python 3:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  binutils \
  libproj-dev \
  gdal-bin \
  libgdal-dev \
  python3-gdal \
  python3-pip \
  python-numpy \
  python-dev

pip install pygdal>=2.1.2,<2.1.3
```

Good luck, this library is not an easy one to work with!